# How to adjust smoothness of spline

Tags: r, spline

```
set.seed(1); x <- round(rnorm(30), 1); y <- sin(pi * x) + rnorm(30)/10
plot(x, y, main = "spline(x,y)  when x has ties")
lines(spline(x, y, n = 201), col = 2)
```

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the smoothness of the spline? Especially from -0.5 and onwards, there are wiggly parts that could be smoother. I have looked at the documentation but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward parameter that does this (something like `spar` in `smooth.spline`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loess is one method, but if you want to use splines, use `smooth.spline`, not the interpolating `spline`

```
set.seed(1); 
x <- round(rnorm(30), 1); 
y <- sin(pi * x) + rnorm(30)/10
plot(x, y, main = "spline(x,y)  when x has ties")
sm <- smooth.spline(x, y, spar = 0.5) # play with spar
pred <- predict(sm, seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1))
lines(pred, col = "red")
```

[image: smoothing splines]

There is a problem with this solution: note that in the negative region where points are less dense, the fit is not so good. `loess` is more local (that's what the l stands for), so it might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I would use LOESS for smoothing:

```
lines(loess.smooth(y=spl[["y"]], x=spl[["x"]], span = 0.05), col=2)
```

Adjust span as needed.